# set main/ root page in TabBarController Swift 4

Tags: storyboard, swift4, tabbarcontroller

I'm still new in IOS development(Swift) and using storyboard.

I have a `TabBarController` that has 3 tab bar items that already embed with ViewControllers on it. I have added a back button on each view controller.

I want to add a main/root page to the `TabBarController` without adding the tab bar item, which mean, each time user click back button, it will navigate to the main page with only consist on 3 tab bar items.

I also want the main /root page being set as the initial page of the tab bar controller.

Below is an illustration for my problem:

[image: Illustration image]